# Cómo restringir que si un usuario ya ha sido logueado, no abra otra sesión?

Tags: c#, mvc

disculpen, para el manejo de sesiones en 1 proyecto web donde quiera restringir que si un usuario ya ha sido logueado no abra otra sesión.

estoy trabajando un proyecto en C# con MVC, tengo que controlar el inicio de sesiones, es decir si un usuario ya inicio sesion y alguien mas quiere abrir otra sesion en otro navegador o en el mismo, con el mismo usuario y contraseña, no se le permita, encontré previamente una respuesta aquí sobre eso pero es de hace 11 años, igual me sirve?
el código que encontré es el siguiente:

```
public partial class page : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected bool Login(string userName) {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> d = Application["UsersLoggedIn"]
            as System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
        if (d != null) {
            lock (d) {
                if (d.Contains(userName)) {
                    // User is already logged in!!!
                    return false;
                }
                d.Add(userName);
            }
        }
        Session["UserLoggedIn"] = userName;
        return true;
    }

    protected void Logout() {
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}

[global.asax]
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script RunAt="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Application["UsersLoggedIn"] = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // NOTE: you might want to call this from the .Logout() method - aswell -, to speed things up
        string userLoggedIn = Session["UserLoggedIn"] == null ? string.Empty ? (string)Session["UserLoggedIn"];
        if (userLoggedIn.Length > 0) {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> d = Application["UsersLoggedIn"] 
                as System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
            if (d != null) {
                lock (d) {
                    d.Remove(userLoggedIn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probaste el código? Falló algo? Qué error encontraste?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Alfabravo en principio no se donde incluir ese código de hace 11 años, lo incluí directamente en el global.asax.cs la otra parte del codigo la que va en el  System.Web.UI.Page donde lo debo incluir? hice un webForm llamado Login y ahi lo incluí, pero me arroja un error donde dice que no encuentra el .MVCApplication

Comment: Entonces sí tienes un ejemplo verificable y un resultado de probarlo. Tu pregunta no debe buscar opiniones (está bien ese código?) sino un problema concreto (usé esto _así_ y salió este error / estalló el servidor / espero _esta_ respuesta). Es imposible que alguien replique el contexto exacto que estás usando sin conocerlo. Puedes [edit] la pregunta y hablar de tu caso

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo en principio no se donde incluir ese código de hace 11 años, lo incluí directamente en el global.asax.cs la otra parte del código la que va en el System.Web.UI.Page donde lo debo incluir? hice un webForm llamado Login y ahí lo incluí, pero me arroja un error donde dice: no se pudo cargar el tipo  zzz.MVCApplication